# Tying ResourceDictionary Control to Multiple Objects

Tags: c#, wpf

at the moment in my resource dictionary I have a telerik Tile control. When it's instantiated a second time I receive the follow error `Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget`

```
public void ListIcon()
{
    var tile = Application.Current.Resources["ListTile"] as Tile;        
    Tiles.Add(tile);
}
```

app.xaml

```
<telerik:Tile x:Key="Calendar" TileType="Double" Background="#FF79256B" Group="Other">
    <telerik:RadCalendar x:Name="calendar" 
                         FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                         FontSize="10"
                         controls:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                         SelectionMode="Extended" 
                         IsTodayHighlighted="True" ViewsHeaderVisibility="Collapsed"                                     
                         SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         Culture="en-US"
                         DayTemplateSelector="{StaticResource EventDayTemplateSelector}"/>
</controls:Tile>
```

Everytime a new user is logged in, ListIcon() is called. If I log out and log into a second user the error occurs. May I ask how do I resolve this.

Comment: You resolve it by not trying to make a single instance of `telerik:Tile` a child of multiple parents at once. Try IsShared="False" on it. If that doesn't work, put it in a DataTemplate.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Hi Ed, I tried setting IsShared but that property wasn't visible for the tiles. I also tried wrapping the tile within a DataTemplate then setting `tile.Content = Application.Current.Resources["ListTile"] as DataTemplate;` but that didn't work as well. Any other tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, try using the `DataTemplate` as a `DataTemplate`. `<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ListTile}" />`

Comment: Hi @Ed, I was wrong earlier. I thought shared would be a visible property of Tile control, but I just had to set `x:Shared=false` and it worked!

Comment: Since I remembered that so horribly wrong that you actually had to figure it out for yourself, you should add it as an answer so I can upvote it!

Comment: Okay @EdPlunkett you still pointed me in right direction and I appreciate that. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply setting the control's `x:Shared="false"` did the trick

```
<telerik:Tile x:Shared="False" x:Key="Calendar" TileType="Double" Background="#FF79256B" Group="Other">
    <telerik:RadCalendar x:Name="calendar" 
                         FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                         FontSize="10"
                         controls:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                         SelectionMode="Extended" 
                         IsTodayHighlighted="True" ViewsHeaderVisibility="Collapsed"                                     
                         SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         Culture="en-US"
                         DayTemplateSelector="{StaticResource EventDayTemplateSelector}"/>
</controls:Tile>
```